# VueJS: Best practices on pre-populating a form with API data and letting update the data?

Tags: vuejs2

What are best practices for pre-populating a form with data from an API?

My use case is that I have a single page application (VueJS) that has a form that contains data from an API and I want the user to be able to edit that data if he needs to change it.

Do I initialize the form values first via the `data()` like so? And if so, how would I merge the API data into the formValues object to use in the template? Should I use computed property here, instead?

```
        <AppSpinner v-if="loading" />
         <form v-if="dataObj" @submit.prevent="updateData">
            <input type="text" v-model="dataObj.text" />
             ....etc ...
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
         </form>
...

data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
      dataObj: {},
    }
},
async created() {
    this.loading = true
    await this.getApiData()
    this.loading = false
},
methods: {
    async getApiData() {
        const response = await APIService.getDataFromApi(this.$route.query.id) //<-- i am using router query here to look up data
        this.dataObj = response.data
    },
   async updateData() {
       const formValues = {
            text: this.dataObj.text,
            ...etc...
       }
       await APIService.updateDataOnServer(formValues)
   }    
}
```

The above workflow seems to work, but I am wondering if this is a best practice? Are there any docs or links that contain a good overview of how I should be setting this up in a Vue app?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're not using placeholders?

```
<input placeholder="text">
```